# Changing Julia dataframe column headers to lowercase?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am looking for a solution to change column's headers to lowercase.

Let's say, I have this dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame(TIME = ["2021-10-21","2021-10-22","2021-10-23"], 
               MQ2= [-1.1, -2, 1],
               MQ3=[-1, -1, 3.1],
               MQ8= [-1, -4.2, 2],
               )
>>>df
    TIME        MQ2     MQ3     MQ8
    String      Float64 Float64 Float64
1   2021-10-21  -1.1    -1.0    -1.0
2   2021-10-22  -2.0    -1.0    -4.2
3   2021-10-23  1.0     3.1     2.0
```

I want to change all of my column's headers, such as  *MQ2* to *mq2*.
May be something like `df.columns.str.lower()` in Python.

Therefore, I can achieve this dataframe:

```
    time        mq2     mq3     mq8
    String      Float64 Float64 Float64
1   2021-10-21  -1.1    -1.0    -1.0
2   2021-10-22  -2.0    -1.0    -4.2
3   2021-10-23  1.0     3.1     2.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would probably do the following:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(TIME = rand(5), MQ2 = rand(5), MQ3 = rand(5), MQ8 = rand(5));

julia> rename!(df, lowercase.(names(df)))
5×4 DataFrame
 Row │ time       mq2        mq3        mq8      
     │ Float64    Float64    Float64    Float64  
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.0796718  0.997022   0.0838867  0.63886
   2 │ 0.923035   0.904928   0.993185   0.36081
   3 │ 0.392671   0.0577061  0.518647   0.81432
   4 │ 0.0377552  0.506528   0.190017   0.488105
   5 │ 0.828534   0.731297   0.383561   0.604786
```

Here I'm using the `DataFrames` `rename` function in its mutating version (hence the bang in `rename!`), with a vector of new column names as the second argument. The new vector is created by getting the current names using `names(df)`, and then broadcasting the `lowercase` function across each element in that vector.

Note that `rename!` also accepts pairs of old/new names if you only want to rename specific columns, e.g. `rename!(df, "TIME" => "time")`

Comment: You just beat me by 1 minute with exactly the same solution ;-)

Comment: Julia SO answers are becoming competitive :)

Comment: `rename!(lowercase, df)` is enough if we try to compete on verbosity :).